# ¿Como puedo hacer que el programa me lea la fecha?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en c# con visual studio y sql server y a la hora de guardar los registros en el windowns form me dice:

> error de conversión al convertir el valor en varchar 12-02-2019 en un dato int.

Aqui el codigo:

```
SqlCommand otroCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Salidas values ('" + txtmotivo.Text + "','" + txttipo.Text+ "','" + dtsalida.Text + "','" + cbempleado.SelectedValue + "')", conexion);
otroCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conexion.Close();
```

Aclaro que la fecha la tengo guardada como date en sql server y estoy utilizando procedimiento almacenado. Y el `dtsalida` es el date time picker en el que quiero almacenar la fecha.

Aquí la tabla:

```
create table Salida(
id int primary key identity,
motivo varchar(60) not null,
tipo varchar(10) not null,
id_empleado int not null,
fecha date not null
)
```

aclaro que no pongo en C# los datos como id e `id_empleado` porque los tengo para que internamente manejen los valores dentro de un `ComboBox` de nombres:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec ObtieneEmpleados", conexion);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        cbempleado.DataSource = dt;
        //Aqui se especifica el campo de la tabla a mostrar, en este caso "nombre"
        cbempleado.DisplayMember = "nombre";
        //Aqui se especifica el valor a manejar internamente por el ComboBox, "id"
        cbempleado.ValueMember = "id";
        conexion.Close();
```

Comment: El error que te da dice que estas tratando de guardar una fecha en un campo que tiene un entero. Deberias mostrarnos como es tu tabla Salidas. Y ahi, por lo menos, no se ve que uses ningun procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Pondre la tabla en un momento.

Comment: Tu error esta en el orden de los parámetros, estas pasandole `dtsalida.Text` a `id_empleado` que es, efectivamente, un int, invertí el nombre de los parámetros en el `insert`, o escribí explicitamente las columnas a realizar el insert en el orden adecuado ([ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error radica en que estas enviando los parámetros en el orden incorrecto.

Según la estructura de tu tabla, la instrucción `INSERT` infiere que estas enviando los parámetros en el siguiente orden:

```
motivo,tipo,id_empleado,fecha
```

Cuando en realidad, estas invirtiendo `id_empleado` y `fecha`

Por lo que, efectivamente, se espera un `int` y llega una fecha.

Para solucionarlo tenes dos caminos.

1. Puedes invertir los parámetros:

```
SqlCommand otroCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Salidas values ('" + txtmotivo.Text + "','" + txttipo.Text+ "','" + cbempleado.SelectedValue + "','" + dtsalida.Text + "')", conexion)
```

2. Puedes definir explícitamente el orden de las columnas en el `INSERT`

```
SqlCommand otroCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Salidas (motivo,tipo,fecha,id_empleado) values ('" + txtmotivo.Text + "','" + txttipo.Text+ "','" + dtsalida.Text + "','" + cbempleado.SelectedValue + "')", conexion);
```

Puedes encontrar más ejemplos de este tema en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Intentare lo primero, pero el id_empleado no lo ocupo para asignar valor en un text box. Eso lo hace automaticamente.

Comment: @ManuelLoquen en el `insert` lo estas ocupando, si no quieres insertarlo, fijate el segundo ejemplo, y de ahí sacalo, luego, no lo pases como parámetro..

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias. intente lo primero y funciona correctamente. Gracias y pasa un buen día :D